# SilverLight like Datagrid Paging in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, pagination

Currently I am searching for the best way for **paginating** the records in **WPF datagrid**.
I have found one best article which provide best way for paginating records in Silverlight over [here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/12/paginating-records-in-silverlight.html).

See it provides also a **fabulous demo**.

Here is one **screen shot.**
[image: SilverLight DataGrid Paging]

But when I have trying it to implement it in **WPF** I **could not implement it?**
I could not found `PagedCollectionView` class and also could not found the **alternative XAML  code** of the **Silverlight code shows is below screen shot**.
[image]

**Could any one provide or suggest the best way for paginating the records in WPF
as like Silverlight?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the `PagedCollectionView` source code from [here](https://silverlight.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Release/Silverlight4/Source/System.Windows.Data/PagedCollectionView/PagedCollectionView.cs) and compile it into your WPF project. I've done this for a WPF project in the past and it works just fine. However, you won't have the supporting types like `DataPager`, but it's easy enough just to write your own or throw some buttons on your view that page through the collection.

Comment: hello kent,, i could not found `using System.Windows.Common;` and `IPagedCollectionView` and so many others in WPF

Comment: Browse the rest of the Silverlight toolkit code and you'll find it: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620

Comment: hey @KentBoogaart i have easily implemented previous next last first button but what i want is a count of total no of pages and which page i currently am in. Can you give me a little idea on this one? I did use PageCount, CurrentPosition through binding but it doesn't give me what i desire. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WPF `DataGrid` doesn't come with pagination by default. You have to have your own custom implementation. Here is a [sample](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/8a2ea78b-f1e3-45b4-93ef-32b2d802ae17/wpf-datagrid-custom-paging-and-sorting.aspx). The sample implements First/Previous as ViewModel commands, however I would advise you to move these commands as part of the control and make a custom `DataGrid` control that you can reuse across application.